# Can a person still see your profile if you were blocked on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I was blocked by a person because we had a fight. A few weeks after, I didn't notice that he was still one of my followers. My profile is on private but can he still see my profile even if I were blocked?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on more than just blocked status.  If you had a public twitter account, for example, a blocked user could just log-out and view the public profile.  A user can follow whomever they want if you don't have privacy settings set up to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if he blocked your account he cannot see you anymore. Since your account is protected and if you want to make sure he cannot read your tweets you might want to disallow his account from following you.